# Read project data from project server using REST API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, project-server

I have two SharePoint environments. In one Project Server is running while in another it's just SharePoint. Let's call these environments `PSE` and `SPE` respectively.

So I am in SPE and trying to read project detail from PSE using API. Problem is there are many Enterprise Custom Fields such as Sponsor Name, Sponsor Units, Stakeholders Unit etc. defined in PSE for which no data is being displayed in the API.

I have tried the following but it is not showing value of these fields.

```
http://PSE/PWA/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('abcdefgh-dc63-e811-810f-0050568b6b32')/IncludeCustomFields

http://PSE/PWA/_api/ProjectData/Projects('abcdefgh-dc63-e811-810f-0050568b6b32')/?$select=StakeHoldersUnit

http://PSE/PWA/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'abcdefgh-dc63-e811-810f-0050568b6b32')
```

I am checking these URLs in IE and they are displaying other standard fields like project title, owner, creation date etc. but not the fields which I mentioned above. So I wanted to ask if it is because that enterprise custom fields are actually not available this way in API?

Any other way to read that data?

Answer (score 1):

in SP2016 I'm using ProjectData endpoint, if I need all fields of a project.

```
http://PSE/PWA/_api/ProjectData/[en-US]/Projects(guid'abcdefgh-dc63-e811-810f-0050568b6b32')
```

In this case you will recieve all (i think) values, not just lookup ids etc.

Comment: I am using Project Server 2013. Not getting all fields, either they are blank or not even in the XML that is being returned even though that project has data in those fields.

Comment: Sorry, i've forgot GUID just before the ID. It's working well for me now. Can you try it out now?

Comment: I have already tried it if you look at the OP where I have used this URL.